# Inserting variable (grabbed from json) into element

Tags: javascript, json, variables, callback, youtube

I have a function to grab a video title from a YouTube json callback, which works - however I'm having issues inserting the variable into an element.

Here is  the feed I'm grabbing:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/2WNrx2jq184?v=2&amp;alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=youtubeFeedCallback"></script>
```

The javascript function I'm using:

```
function youtubeFeedCallback(data) {
var info = data.entry.title.$t;
document.write(info);
}
```

This works fine, but I'd like to insert it into a div with the ID "box".

Usually I would use the following (and add it to the function - and remove the document.write):

```
var box = document.getElementById('box');
box.innerHTML = info;
```

I just cannot get this to work though. What would be the correct way to achieve what I'm trying to do? Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/b3VYT/

Comment: Maybe this will help you? http://jsfiddle.net/b3VYT/1/

Comment: So simple... I guess the script has to be below the element?  I spent many hours trying to work this one out due to all my linked scripts being at the top of the page. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either make sure that the script is below the element or wrap your code in a `document.ready` callback so that it is not run until after the DOM is loaded.

http://jsfiddle.net/b3VYT/1

Comment: To make it execute after the DOM is loaded, would it just be a case of adding `window.onload = youtubeFeedCallback(data) {`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the  element that you are using is declared prior to your script executing:

```
<div id='test'></div>
<script>
    function youtubeFeedCallback(data) {
         document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = data.entry.title.$t;
    }
</script>
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/bA2zc/)